# SQL Parameter in dotNET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

here is a little problem ...

```
string SQL = @"INSERT INTO [Answers] ([UserID],[QuestionID],[SelectedIndex]) 
  VALUES(@uid,@qid,@sin)";
    SqlParameter[] par = new SqlParameter[] { 
    new SqlParameter("@uid",this.userid),
    new SqlParameter("@qid",this.questionid),
    new SqlParameter("@sin",this.qOptions.SelectedIndex)
    };
```

this does not work ... Why not? i dunno, but the firs one is bigint in SQL (microsoft 2005)
and in dotNET side its an int  ... second one is a an SQL uniqueidentifier while its a string in dotNEWT but it works that way i have experience .. third one is an integer in SQL and int in dotNET ... since dotNET does not have any major malfunction, what is my major malfunction? :) thank you sargeant in advance :)))

Comment: Would be nice if you could use a bit better formatting to help make things clearer. For example, format each parameter type. Also, isn't a BigInt an int64 in .NET?

Comment: What is the error that you're seeing?

Comment: Consider posting the table definition as well as the declarations for the `userid`, `questionid` and `qOptions` fields (or props).

Answer (score 1):

`uniqueidentifier` should map to `Guid` rather than `string`, I believe. What happens if you make it a `Guid` instead (just for a test value)? See the [`SqlDbType` enumeration docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) for a list of mappings.

It would also help if you'd say in what *way* it doesn't work, by the way. That's *always* a good idea when you're reporting a problem. Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

[SqlGuid's Implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlguid.op_implicit.aspx) expects a `Guid`, not an `int`. Alternatively, [there are explicit constructors for `String`, `Byte[]` and `int` as well.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlguid.sqlguid.aspx)